# Writing functions to allow user define file name and enter file contents

Tags: python, function, file, for-loop

I am learning Python as a beginner and  have a question that I couldn't figure out. I need to write functions to allow users to setup/give a file a name and then enter contents.

The error message I got is: `"Str' object is not callable`. I don't know how to fix this. Please could you help me out. Many thanks!

The code is as follows:

=========================================

```
WRITE = "w"
APPEND = "a"

fName = ""
def fileName():  #to define name of the file.
    fName = input("Please enter a name for your file: ")
    fileName = open(fName, WRITE)
    return fileName

#now to define a function for data entry
dataEntry = ""
def enterData():
    dataEntry = input("Please enter guest name and age, separated by a coma: ")
    dataFile = open(fName, APPEND(dataEntry))
    fName.append(dataEntry)
    return dataFile 

#to determine if it's the end of data entry
moreEntry = input("Anymore guest: Y/N  ")
while moreEntry != "N":
    enterData()    #here to call function to repeat data entry

fName.close()



fileName()
enterData()
print("Your file has been completed!")

fileContents = fName.readline()
print(fileContents)
```

Comment: Show the exact error with trace. You're trying to treat a string as a function somewhere.

Comment: `fileName = open(fName, WRITE)` is overwriting your function name with a string; you're naming the variable and the function the same thing. I wouldn't have thought that that would persist into the global scope, but it seems to be. I'd write an answer, but I'm clearly rusty when it comes to Python scoping, so I couldn't give a great explanation.

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback.  You should be getting other errors.  Is this the exact code that you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and... I seeing the error as line 14

```
 14     dataFile = open(fName, APPEND(dataEntry))
```

- APPEND appears to be a str. It does not appear to be a function.
- fName is not declared in this scope. Your function spacing is off. Maybe you meant to run the all the code in order rather than in parts? 
  As it is, fName is declared and defined once globally (line 4), declared and defined in function filename() (line 6).
  fName is also referred to in the function (line 7) Called unsuccessfully in line 14

  ```
   dataFile = open(fName, APPEND(dataEntry)) # fName has not been declared in function enterData()
  ```

I suspect your code would work if you reordered your lines and not use functions (due to references) Also, please close your files. EG

```
f = open ("somefile.txt", "a+")
...
f.close() #all in the same block.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the inputs. Much appreciated. I've reworked the code a bit, and to put all data entry into a list first, then try to append the list to the file. It works, to a certain extent (about 80%, perhaps!)

However, I now have another problem. When I tried to open the file to append the list, it says "No such file or directory" next to the code (line31): "myFile = open(fName, APPEND)". But I thought I declared and then let user define the name at the beginning? How should I make it work, please?

## Thanks in advance again!

```
WRITE = "w"
APPEND = "a"

fName = ""
def fileName():  #to define name of the file.
    fName = input("Please enter a name for your file: ")
    fileName = open(fName, WRITE)
    fileName.close()
    return fileName


#now to define a function for data entry
dataEntry = ""
dataList = []
def enterData():
    dataEntry = input("Please enter guest name and age, separated by a coma: ")
    dataList.append(dataEntry)
    return 

fileName()
enterData()

#to determine if it's the end of data entry
moreEntry = input("Anymore guest: Y/N  ")
if moreEntry == "Y":
    enterData()
else:
    print("Your file has been completed successfully!")


myFile = open(fName, APPEND)    
myFile.append(dataList)  
myFile.close()


fileContents = fName.readline()
print(fileContents)
```